# Set of C strings

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    set<char[10]> rno;
    rno.insert("208/CO/11");
    rno.insert("206/CO/11");
    rno.insert("209/CO/11");
    rno.insert("208/CO/11");
    set<char[10]>::iterator it;
    for(it=rno.begin();rno.end()!=it;it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code does not work? If I replace char[10] by a string it works fine but if c++ is superset of c why is this associative container is not compatible with c strings?

Comment: "Why this code does not work?" What do you mean by does not work? Crashes? Doesn't compile?

Comment: char[10]..You  dont have a delimiter NULL character `\0` in that

Answer (score 7):

The problem is `std::set` requires a comparator and by default that is `operator<`. Your problem is there isn't aren't any logical operators defined for raw arrays.

However, `std::string` does have `operator<` defined, so that's why it works with `std::string` but not `char[10]`.

You can however provide your own if you wish, but unless you need something specific that isn't provided by the standard library, using `std::string` is the way to go. You could also use `std::array<char, 10>` or even `std::vector<char>` both of these also have `operator<` defined.

Addendum: This would *work* (and by work I mean compile) if you had `char*` because pointers being memory addresses can be compared using `operator<`. BUT it wouldn't do what you expect because it would essentially sort the content of the set by the addresses of each char array instead lexicographically comparing each string. Which is why `std::set<std::string>` is the superior option.

Addendum #2: Another thing that raw arrays lack is built-in copy and assignment which also happens to be a requirement for most (if not all) standard containers.

Comment: That doesn't explain why this works with `char*` instead of `char[10]` though.

Comment: @Serdalis Yes it does. You can compare pointers with operator<, but not char[10]. Try it.

Comment: The problem is more likely to be that plain arrays are not copyable or assignable.

Comment: @juanchopanza that is also a possibility but even if they were, operator< will bite you.

Comment: It is more than a possibility. This would fail, even if you provided a comparator for `char[10]`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, I checked with vector which doesn't need operator<. I'll edit to mention this.